# Why should I use local-variable type Inference for lambda parameters if I can skip it?

Tags: java, lambda, java-11, type-inference

Java 11 introduced local-variable type Inference for lambda parameters. For example:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c").map((var a) -> "ok")
```

My question is: why should I use it, if I can skip it. For example:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c").map(a -> "ok")
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JEP 323](https://openjdk.org/jeps/323) states the following goal:

> - Align the syntax of a formal parameter declaration in an implicitly typed lambda expression with the syntax of a local variable declaration.

And it states as motiviation:

> A lambda expression may be implicitly typed, where the types of all its formal parameters are inferred:
>
> ```
>     (x, y) -> x.process(y)    // implicitly typed lambda expression
> ```
>
> Java SE 10 makes implicit typing available for local variables:
>
> ```
>     var x = new Foo();
>     for (var x : xs) { ... }
>     try (var x = ...) { ... } catch ...
> ```
>
> For uniformity with local variables, we wish to allow 'var' for the formal parameters of an implicitly typed lambda expression:
>
> ```
>     (var x, var y) -> x.process(y)   // implicit typed lambda expression
> ```
>
> One benefit of uniformity is that modifiers, notably annotations, can be applied to local variables and lambda formals without losing brevity:
>
> ```
>     @Nonnull var x = new Foo();
>     (@Nonnull var x, @Nullable var y) -> x.process(y)
> ```

---

Should you use it if you can skip it?

There might be contexts where you are required to use it (if you work in a project with a rigid coding convention that mandates the use). In other contexts it is probably opinion based.

My specific opinion: if you don't need it then don't use it.

- You will need it if you need to annotate the lambda parameters
- otherwise leave it out